# What's the difference between .col and ['col'] in pandas

Tags: pandas

I've been using pandas for a little while now and I've realised that I use

```
 df.col
 df['col']
```

interchangeably. Are they actually the same or am I missing something?

Comment: Main difference is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35850290/2285236

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from the link in the comments.

```
df.col
```

Simply refers to an attribute of the dataframe, similar to say

```
df.shape
```

Now if 'col' is a column name in the dataframe then accessing this attribute returns the column as series. This sometimes will be sufficient but

```
df['col']
```

will always work, and can also be used to add a new column to a dataframe.

Comment: Are there differences between df['col'] and df[:, 'col']?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is kind of obvious.....

You cannot use `df.col` if the column name `'col'` has a space in it. But `df['col']` always works.
e.g,

`df['my col']` works but `df.my col` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll note there's a difference in how some methods consume data. For example, in the LifeTimes library if I use dataframe.col with some methods, the method will consider the column to be an ndarray and throw an exception that the data must be 1-dimensional.

If however I use dataframe['col'] then the method will consume the data as expected.