# Python: AttributeError while creating a new property of an object via assignment

Tags: python, object, exception

I do the following assignment (File is a class):

```
file_object = File()
file_object.file_type = file_type
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'file_type'
```

How can it be?

I thought, that you could add attributes dynamically (and it worked always before).

I've upgraded my python to 2.7.13, and now I have this problem.

`File` (in my case) has `__dict__` and does not have `__slot__`:

```
>>> print dir(File)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'factory', 'method_name']
```

Comment: Which versión did you have prior to the upgrade (when this worked)?

Comment: @sancho.s: 2.7.6 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, lack of a `__dict__` in your class, prevents dynamically adding an attribute.
See answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285287/2707864

Your class may have the `__slots__` special attribute, preventing addition of `__dict__`.
See answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529099/2707864

Check other possibly useful questions/answers:

[Why is adding attributes to an already instantiated object allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569018/why-is-adding-attributes-to-an-already-instantiated-object-allowed)

[How to add property to a class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically)  (marginal)

Comment: A good idea, but no. I've added `dir(File)` output to the question. And as I said already: it happened after python upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is reading File() as an object, not a class - https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html.

Comment: There is no builtin object/class called `File`.

Comment: Pasting a link to docs for old version is not a good idea, additionally OP said which version of Python is used.